# Laravel - rota default

Tags: laravel

Ola sou novo no Laravel e queria saber se tem como deixar uma rota default para caso alguem erre a rota digitada o return seja da pagina return

Comment: O que precisa é a [*fallback route*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#fallback-routes)?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, vlw e isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma simples maneira de resolver isso:

```
Route::any('{any}', function () {
    return redirect('/');
});
```

O 'any' se refere a 'qualquer um'. Então independente do verbo HTTP usado ou da rota digitada ele retornaria para home ('/').

Mais detalhes vc encontra na própria [documentaçaõ do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing).